# Approach to return typeahead query result according to the user making the request

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a table in my database and it has a NAME column in it. User can search based on the NAME and I have to give suggestions to the user. SO I have generated a trie of all the names present in that table and returns the suggested names based on the prefix. 
 
But the problem is all the users don't have access to all the records of the table. But there is a common trie generated for all the users.  
The search complexity now is O(M) where M is the length of the longest name in the table.
So is there any way I can show the results based on the user and not increasing the complexity by much?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever way you try it, you will need to cross-match the full result-set with the results that are accessible by the user. This means either you must introduce a join to the query or add some code to filter the records post-query. I doubt you will be able to avoid both of these options.

You mention that your search is based on a prefix match, which means that it should be straightforward to use an index on the name column so that you are performing a seek query rather than a scan. If you are doing this, could you clarify why the complexity of the query is informed by the maximum name column value length?

I also expect that you could optimise the query to only return a limited number of results, then encourage the user to narrow the search criteria with additional characters.

This is as much as I can suggest without more specific information on the technologies used, query statements and underlying table structure.

Comment: I'm using the trie which generated the tree of all the letters in the names. And then if it finds the match to the prefix, it uses DFS to find all the results (in my case I'm only returning the top 10 results). So this is why the complexity of the search is based on maximum name length because that would be the depth of the tree. And as I mentioned I'm only returning the top 10 results to the user.